# Setting up cloud watch exporter for prometheus on mesosphere DCOS cluster

Tags: mesos, amazon-cloudwatch, mesosphere, prometheus

I have set up cloud watch exporter for Prometheus on my **AWS mesosphere DCOS cluster**. I have '**CloudWatchFullAccess**' policy enabled. But meter, '`cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_error`' shows non-zero value. I want to know why the scrape is giving error.

Where can I check logs or how to debug this problem?

Also the config file I am using is

```
{
   "region": "ap-southeast-1",
   "metrics": [
        {"aws_namespace": "AWS/ELB", "aws_metric_name": "HealthyHostCount",
         "aws_dimensions": ["AvailabilityZone", "LoadBalancerName"],
         "aws_dimension_select": {"LoadBalancerName": ["name of my LB"]},
         "aws_statistics": ["Sum"]
        }
      ]
}
```

but I do not any meters in addition to meters - `cloudwatch_requests_total`,
`cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_duration_seconds`, `cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_error` exposed to Prometheus.

How to get additional meters from cloudwatch_exporter?

Comment: Author of the cloudwatch_exporter here, can you verify that there's credentials showing up under `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ROLENAME` ? Also, is there any output on stderr/stdout?

Comment: Thanks for looking into the question. When I try to execute the curl command I get, "Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80: Connection refused" error

Comment: In my set up, cloudwatch_exporter is listening on port '9106'. So I am looking up for metrics on http://<hostname>:9106/metrics . All the metrics should be exposed here, right?

Comment: That sounds like a network problem on your machine if you can't get to 169.254.169.254. As a workaround I'd suggest creating an IAM user and putting the credentials in the environment variables. Yes, that's where they'll be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you're trying to use an IAM instance profile, but you can't access http://169.254.169.254. This is some form of problem with your network setup, as this should work out of the box on EC2.

You have two options.

1. You can fix your network setup so you can get to 169.254.169.254 again.
2. Or you could create an IAM user with the `cloudwatch:ListMetrics` and `cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics` IAM permissions, and generate accesskeys and put them in `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` or `~/.aws/credentials`.

See https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter#credentials-and-permissions

Comment: I'm running the cloudwatch_exporter docker container. How can I provide AWS credentials to the docker container?

Comment: After giving the correct credentials inside the docker comtainer, I got the relevant metrics from cloud watch exporter. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Below is my config file

```
{
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "metrics": [
    {"aws_namespace": "AWS/ELB", "aws_metric_name": "HealthyHostCount",
     "aws_dimensions": ["us-west-2a", "test"], "aws_statistics": ["Average"]},
    {"aws_namespace": "AWS/ELB", "aws_metric_name": "UnHealthyHostCount",
     "aws_dimensions": ["us-west-2a", "test"], "aws_statistics": ["Average"]},
    {"aws_namespace": "AWS/ELB", "aws_metric_name": "RequestCount",
     "aws_dimensions": ["us-west-2a", "test"], "aws_statistics": ["Sum"]},
    {"aws_namespace": "AWS/ELB", "aws_metric_name": "Latency",
     "aws_dimensions": ["us-west-2a", "test"], "aws_statistics": ["Average"]},
    {"aws_namespace": "AWS/ELB", "aws_metric_name": "SurgeQueueLength",
     "aws_dimensions": ["us-west-2a", "test"], "aws_statistics": ["Maximum",    "Sum"]},
    ]
}
```

I can see below output

```
cloudwatch_requests_total 10.0

cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_duration_seconds 2.571412647

cloudwatch_exporter_scrape_error 0.0
```

But why not other metrics?

Comment: For the namespace AWS/ELB, valid aws_dimensions are LoadBalancerName  and AvailabilityZone. Refer [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-metricscollected.html). You need to change your config file, and enter valid dimesnions or no dimnsions to get metrics of namespace AWS/ELB. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is working for me , I have question , so if we deploy that in docker it wll only scrap metrics if the native host?